# Datagridview custom row highlight

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (WinForms, C#). All I wanted to do is to divide grid on left/ right parts. So, when I click on left part (3,3) will highlights for example, when click on right part (6,6) will be highlighted.

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
-------------------------
 1      1       2     2
 3      3       4     4
 5      5       6     6
```

Getting the value not a problem, but highlights.. ?

```
    int iCol = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    if (iCol == 0 || iCol == 1)   // left side
    { 

    }
    else  // right side
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you, but you should not write column indexes directly in code, I think coltroling indexes with mathematical expression is better solution.
Also this code would be slow with big data, so that you can use column select. But if you use column select, it would prevent reordering rows when you clicked column header.

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect
    If e.ColumnIndex < DataGridView1.ColumnCount / 2 Then
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            If c.Index < DataGridView1.ColumnCount / 2 Then
                For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    r.Cells(c.Index).Style.BackColor = Color.Blue
                Next
            Else
                For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    r.Cells(c.Index).Style.BackColor = Color.Gray
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            If c.Index >= DataGridView1.ColumnCount / 2 Then
                For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    r.Cells(c.Index).Style.BackColor = Color.Blue
                Next
            Else
                For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    r.Cells(c.Index).Style.BackColor = Color.Gray
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for wrong explanation here. But I want to highlight the row with (3,3), not first 2 columns(left part)

Comment: Ok it is not too much different code. With the same logic slect the only one row using dataGirdView.Rows(e.RowIndex).selected = True but this is the logic real code implementation would be some different